# how to place a file inside .bashrc

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following a tutorial on the link https://github.com/birlrobotics/birl_baxter/wiki and I was told as folows:

**Finally, after doing catkin_make, place the newly created ~/ros/indigo/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash file inside .bashrc**

```
cd ~
emacs .bashrc
source ~/ros/indigo/rbx_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

When I run the command ***emacs .bashrc*** the emacs editor opens but I am not sure what I am expected to do after that .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253717/how-to-place-a-file-inside-.bashrc/) by [fundamentals](https://answers.ros.org/users/29111/fundamentals/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Go to the end of the file that you just opened and paste the following:

```
source ~/ros/indigo/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

then save the file, exit the editor.

Now continue with whatever the documentation tells you to do.

---

Note that this of course assumes that you actually have a directory `ros/indigo/catkin_ws` in your home directory and that you built the workspace.

Note also that if you ever delete `~/ros/indigo/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`, every new terminal that you open will complain about `~/ros/indigo/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` not existing.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2